# How to input a matrix and receive value (or array of values) using machine learning in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, matrix, scikit-learn

I have a bunch of binary 8x15 matrixes and I want to determine which index (row and column) of the matrix breaks the pattern.

Say I have the following matrix (simplified to 5x5 for ease, because the problem remains the same):

```
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 0 1 0
1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 0
```

This matrix should return [3, 3], because that position breaks the pattern of filling the matrix column by column with 1.

The following example should return [3, 1]:

```
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 0
```

The following example, however, doesn't show that problem, so it should return [-1, -1] or something (suggestions?):

```
1 1 1 1 0 
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0 0
```

How should I approach this problem using machine learning?

Currently, I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns: the first one contains the matrix (so an array of 8 arrays of 15 positions; therefore, 8x15 matrix), while the second one contains the expected return / result:

```
                      State                                  Result
0   [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]...   [-1, -1]
1   [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]...   [-1, -1]
2   [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]...   [-1, -1]
3   [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]...   [-1, -1]
4   [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]...   [-1, -1]
```

dtypes:

```
State     object
Result    object
dtype: object
```

So one entry of the dataframe above would have the first column with a value like:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

And its second column would have the value [6, 3].

Then I split it in 2 dataframes, X and y:

```
X = states_data.drop(columns=['Result'])
y = states_data[['Result']]
```

After that, I tried to use DecisionTreeClassifier with sklearn to solve the problem:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)
X_train = X_train.reset_index(drop=True)
X_test = X_test.reset_index(drop=True)
y_train = y_train.reset_index(drop=True)
y_test = y_test.reset_index(drop=True)

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
predictions = pd.DataFrame(predictions, columns = ['Result'])

score = accuracy_score(y_test['Result'], predictions['Result'])
print(score)
```

However, in this line:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong?

Some additional information:

X_train.dtypes returns:

```
State    object
dtype: object
```

y_train.dtypes returns:

```
Result    object
dtype: object
```

Both X_train.shape and y_train.shape return:

```
(543, 1)
```

Comment: Could you add the whole code of your program?

Comment: The code before is just to generate the data (which I have provided), so I don't think it's important to solve my problem. I would provide it if I could, but it contains sensitive information about the company. What other information do you need? I could provide it

Comment: I'd like to test some things. Fist of all would be to change target value ```y``` to a different format - instead of list of lists I'd use ```tuple``` or some sort of string representation. That way it's possible to eliminate the problem connected with ```float``` casting. If that wouldn't help then I'd do the same for the ```x``` input.

Comment: I think that the solution for your problem may be connected with OneHotEncoding (https://www.educative.io/blog/one-hot-encoding) but to test it out I'd need a base script from which I could start debugging.

Comment: You are giving invalid inputs to ```fit()```. See [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.fit). And I don't expect a classifier will perform well for your problem.

Comment: @relent95, what model would you recommend for it? I'm a beginner on the subject

Comment: @mlokos, I tried to convert everything to tuples and it didn't work. I just get more problems related to float. But thanks!

Comment: Try [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No, you should convert a Pandas data frame to a NumPy array. Try something like ```X = numpy.stack([m.reshape(-1) for m in states_data['State']])```.

Comment: Try y = states_data['Result']